# C# Virtual Mode for my DataGridView which is Bound to a BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview, datagrid

I am still a bit new to C# so please excuse me if this is a silly question. I have googled this many times before asking here because I cannot seem to find a clear and specific answer to my problem.

Currently, I have a DGV that is bound via dataGridView.datasource to a Binding List. In the context of my program, the list can be populated very quickly which leads to a performance issue with the DGV trying to keep up. I have heard that virtual mode for the DGV will help with the large number of entries I am dealing with. Any advice with how to proceed? I know that enabling virtual mode is just setting the property to true and handling some exceptions, but I've also been told that my previous dataGridView.datasource call to bind my list to the DGV cannot be used in this mode.

Followup Question: If virtualization is not the best way for me to go about fixing the performance issue, then what is a good alternative?

Comment: Can you provide the troubling code, and how many entries are we talking, roughly?

Comment: There are a ton of functions and they are far from condensed so there wasn't really a good way to copy/paste anything in here. Basically, my list constantly has items added to it and after a certain button on the form is hit, the dataGridView.datasource property is set equal to the binding list. (It is previously set to NULL). This call can happen after the binding list has, say, 10,000 values or more in it.